# Django file upload with unique name

Tags: django, file-upload, django-forms

I try to upload a file in Django by following Django docs.

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

But it overwrites the name.txt file when I upload it. How can I make sure that it has a unique name in that folder? (It may be saved as name(1).txt)

P.S: Django handles it when saving a model with File field. However, I use forms and I need to handle it manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll get a unique id if you use the uuid library

```
import uuid

def handle_uploaded_file(f):

    name = 'some/file/%s.txt' % uuid.uuid1()

    with open(name, 'wb+') as destination:
       for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html